# HelloWorld in JGRASP getting error when compiled

Tags: java, jgrasp

I'm on a max and using the latest JGRASP with JDK installed. When I try to run:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("Hello World!");
   {
}
```

I get this error:

```
----jGRASP exec: javac -g HelloWorld.java
HelloWorld.java:7: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
1 error
```

I am new to both Java and JGRASP. Brand new. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a `{` instead of a `}`, after the `System.out.println` line.

Comment: OMG, I looked at that 10x and still missed it. I suck. Thank you.